# how to speed this R code in SparkR

Tags: r, query-optimization, sparkr

I have the following code that works in regular R but I would like to port to SparkR to speed it up:

```
sample_data<- structure(list(idnty_frst_nm = structure(c(3L, 2L), .Label = c("","I", "Ima"), class = "factor"), idnty_last_nm = structure(c(2L,2L), .Label = c("", "NINJA"), class = "factor"), PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE = c(9021099834,9021099834), RECEIPT_NUMBER = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("","MISC1234567"), class = "factor"), a_nbr.1 = structure(c(2L,2L), .Label = c("", "A079577094"), class = "factor"), ssn = structure(c(2L,2L), .Label = c("", "123-456-7891"), class = "factor"), idnty_dob = structure(c(2L,2L), .Label = c("", "1/2/2020"), class = "factor"), a_nbr = structure(c(2L,2L), .Label = c("", "AO79577094"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("idnty_frst_nm","idnty_last_nm", "PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE", "RECEIPT_NUMBER","a_nbr.1", "ssn", "idnty_dob", "a_nbr"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame") 

sample_data$name<-paste(sample_data$idnty_frst_nm, sample_data$idnty_last_nm)
innov.df<-sample_data
rownames(innov.df)<-1:nrow(innov.df)

#Checking for duplicate names, using 'agrep' function and storing intermediate 
#results in table 'p'

p<-data.frame(a=integer(),b=integer())
k<-1
for(i in 1:nrow(innov.df)){
  for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name,
                  ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                  max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
    if(i!=j)
    {
      if((innov.df[i,2]==innov.df[j,2])&&(innov.df[i,3]==innov.df[j,3]))
      {
        p[k,1]<-min(i,j)
        p[k,2]<-max(i,j)
        k<-k+1
      }
    }
  }
}

p<-unique(p)
```

Any ideas on how I could speed it up would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please include a sample of your data with `dput()`.

Comment: Here is a working example:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just some small examples how you could speed up that process, although there are definitly better ones. I tried to maintain the structure of your loops and just optimized them.

Instead of appending to a dataframe in a loop, I would **create a list at the beginning** and assign values to it and at the end bind them together. This already brings you already about 40% speedup.

The next function just uses `as.character()` in the second if statement, as they are otherwise factors. This brings another 10%.

The last but one function uses a **matrix instead of data.frame** and appends the values to it. And the last one implements all the good things from the above :)

Until now, no data.tables or apply functions or even parallel processing were used, which would definitly speed up the code even more, but I'm sure others are more experienced with those and may show even better practices.

```
fdf <- function(){
  p <- data.frame(a=integer(),b=integer())
  for (i in 1:nrow(innov.df)){
    for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name, ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                    max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
      if (i!=j) {
        if ((innov.df[i,2]==innov.df[j,2])&&(innov.df[i,3]==innov.df[j,3])) {
          p[k,1] <- min(i,j)
          p[k,2] <- max(i,j)
          k <- k+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p <- data.frame(matrix(p[!is.na(p)],ncol=2, byrow = T))
  colnames(p) <- c("a","b")
  p
}
flist <- function(){
  p <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(innov.df)) {
    for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name,
                    ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                    max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
      if (i!=j) {
        if ((innov.df[i,2])==(innov.df[j,2])&&
            (innov.df[i,3])==(innov.df[j,3]))
        {
          p[[k]] <- cbind(a=min(i,j), b=max(i,j))
          k <- k+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p <- data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), p))
  colnames(p) <- c("a","b")
  p
}
flistOpti <- function(){
  p <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(innov.df)) {
    for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name,
                    ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                    max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
      if (i!=j) {
        if (as.character(innov.df[i,"idnty_last_nm"])==as.character(innov.df[j,"idnty_last_nm"]) && 
            (as.character(innov.df[i,"PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE"])==as.character(innov.df[j,"PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE"]))) {

          p[[k]] <- cbind(a=min(i,j), b=max(i,j))
          k <- k+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p <- data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), p))
  colnames(p) <- c("a","b")
  p
}
fma <- function(){
  p <- matrix(c(a=integer(),b=integer()), ncol=2)
  for (i in 1:nrow(innov.df)){
    for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name, ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                    max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
      if (i!=j) {
        if ((innov.df[i,2]==innov.df[j,2])&&(innov.df[i,3]==innov.df[j,3])) {
          p <- c(p, cbind(min(i,j),max(i,j)))
          k <- k+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p <- data.frame(matrix(p[!is.na(p)],ncol=2, byrow = T))
  colnames(p) <- c("a","b")
  p
}
fmaOptim <- function(){
  p <- matrix(c(a=integer(),b=integer()), ncol=2)
  for (i in 1:nrow(innov.df)){
    for (j in agrep(innov.df$name[i], innov.df$name, ignore.case=TRUE, value=FALSE,
                    max.distance = 0.07, useBytes = TRUE)) {
      if (i!=j) {
        if (as.character(innov.df[i,"idnty_last_nm"])==as.character(innov.df[j,"idnty_last_nm"]) && 
           (as.character(innov.df[i,"PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE"])==as.character(innov.df[j,"PERSON_IDENTIFIER_VALUE"]))) {
          p <- c(p, cbind(min(i,j),max(i,j)))
          k <- k+1
        }
      }
    }
  }
  p <- data.frame(matrix(p[!is.na(p)],ncol=2, byrow = T))
  colnames(p) <- c("a","b")
  p
}
```

---

```
library(microbenchmark)
mc <- microbenchmark(times = 1000,
  fdfR = fdf(),
  flistR = flist(),
  flistOptiR = flistOpti(),
  fmaR = fma(),
  fmaOptimR = fmaOptim()
)
mc

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min      lq        mean   median        uq       max neval cld
       fdfR 782.725 831.056 1059.789348 883.3505 1018.7130 24732.664  1000   c
     flistR 449.700 470.089  576.289776 489.5335  545.9820 23600.677  1000  b 
 flistOptiR 394.949 417.227  581.230449 435.1620  492.9325 45357.250  1000  b 
       fmaR 370.784 389.664  484.542990 402.5015  452.3420 24713.785  1000 ab 
  fmaOptimR 313.015 335.670  431.991723 349.8295  393.0620 25033.973  1000 a
```

You could also put the `nrow(innov.df)` outside the `for(i in 1:nrow(innov.df))`,as otherwise it calculates the number of rows in every loop. This did not result in speed up time, but the number of rows in the example is just 2, so  its probably to small to show some improvements. This small example shows that with bigger amount of rows, there is some small performance optimization to be made.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100000, 1,10),
  id = 1:100000
)

mc <- microbenchmark(times = 1000,
                     Nrow = {for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {}},
                     NoNrow = for (i in 1:100000) {}
)
mc
```

---

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq        mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   Nrow 3.895500 4.060691 4.311444202 4.1584845 4.3051750 10.454830  1000   b
 NoNrow 3.384633 3.516409 3.734800425 3.6017420 3.7303085 36.621923  1000  a
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you!!